# Jquery simple Ajax Post PHP not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a simple code but is not working. I want to create a more complex function but I just need the basic structure.

HTML

```
<span class="cleanreport">Delete Record</span>
```

Javascript:

```
$( ".cleanreport" ).click(function() {

var token = "test";

$.ajax({
data: {"data": token},
type: "post",
url: "clean.php",
success: function (data) {
console.log(data);
$('.test').html(data);
  }
    });
});
```

PHP clean.php

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo $data;
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you test your PHP $_POST. if its empty try this $tempData = file_get_contents("php://input"); print PHP error_log or dump output  to test PHP.

Comment: `type: "post",` ==> `method: "POST",`

Comment: I have other ajax calls on my website with post and form that are working, only this not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var token = "test";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "clean.php",
    data: {id: token},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        // some debug could be here
    },
    error: function(a,b,c) {
        // some debug could be here
    }
});
```

If not, please debug `success` and `error` parameters using `console.log()`.

Based on [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) setting `type` is an alias for `method` so this could not be a problem in you case for sure.

Comment: Sorry but still not working. I tried with console.log but nothing displays, also not errors on error.log

Comment: Ok fixed, just need to add the ajax function inside a  $(function() { .... }); Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".cleanreport" ).click(function() {
    var token = "test";
    $.post('clean.php",
    {
       data: token
    },
    function (data,status) {
        //console.log(data);
        $('.test').html(data);
    });
});
```